# Re throw exception

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code:

```
public static string Get(string requestUri)
{
    try
    {
        return GetStringAsync(requestUri).Result;
    }
    catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aggregateException);
        throw;
    }
}
```

When the try block throws an exception, the program goes as it should in the catch block and displays the information about the error.

The problem is that once arrived at the rethrow, the debugger stops and raises me again the same exception but at the same level, despite it is supposed to go up one level in the stack...

I did not find a solution on the Internet, all examples correspond to my code.

**EDIT**

Your solution is working for the code above, but I have another which doesn't work too :

```
    public static string Post(string requestUriString, string s)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUriString);
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            return new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(webException);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is your debugger set to stop on thrown exceptions?

Comment: @Hasan `throw` is commonly used in `catch` blocks where the exception is meant to be logged and propagated to the calling context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the way `AggregateException` is handled; change your method to an `async` method (which eliminates the `AggregateException` wrapper), and `throw` will work as expected:

```
public static async Task<string> Get(string requestUri)
{
    try
    {
        return await GetStringAsync(requestUri);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)  // Or, specify the expected exception type
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
        throw;  // can be caught in the calling code
    }
}
```